# How convert JSON data to html table

Tags: html, json, url, html-table

I get real-time statistics for myself and the data in JSON format. The problem is, I can not figure how can I get this table in html web page.

Data can be found at: http://testinki.info/apidata/

I have tried something like this, but without success:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <div id="id01"></div>
      <script>
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://testinki.info/apidata/";

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
          }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        function myFunction(response) {
            var arr = JSON.parse(response);
            var i;
            var out = "<table>";

            for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                out += "<tr><td>" + 
                arr[i].apikey +
                "</td></tr>"
            }
            out += "</table>"
            document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? How to solve the problem?

Comment: any console errors? any unexpected behavior ?

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: One of your problems may be that you aren't ever closing the `<tr>` tag created. I suggest using HTML Nodes (a quick Google should give you an idea) to get the data out. Give me a second and if no one has posted an answer I'll work one out. EDIT: Also, just noticed you don't close the quote around the `</td>` element.

Comment: I did not get any information out. Simply the script does not do anything. I do not get any errors.
Yes, one problem is the </tr>, but yes, something should get...

Comment: `(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)` condition always failed which is responsible for calling `myFunction()`.

Answer (score 0):

[AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) might be a good solution for the task. With data from your link, code will look something like this:

```
  Api key: {{data.apikey}}
  <br>
  User:
  <pre>{{data.data|json}}</pre>
  <br>
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="member in data.Members">
      <td>{{member.name}}</td>
      <td>{{member.info}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

```
angular
.module("app", [])
.controller("ctrl", function ($http, $scope, $http) {
  $http
  .get("http://testinki.info/apidata/")
  .then(function (res) {
    $scope.data = res;
  })
})
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/befoliteseze/2/edit?html,js,output). I've changed `$http` to `$timeout` and predefined data since your API does not allow cross-origin requests.